# Disable Record Macro in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, visual-studio-2012

How can I disable the 'Macro Recording' option from the Customize Status Bar, so that the user can't enable it by clicking on the list?
Or How can I remove the item 'Macro Recording' totally?

[image]

Comment: Should they be able to enable it by going elsewhere?

Comment: No all other possible ways, ie in certain tabs, are blocked by customizing the Ribbon, but this can't be done with the following `code`<command idMso="MacroRecord" enabled="false"/>.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [edit] you question to give us more details (all users, all files, etc.) about what/why you are doing this so we understand the situation better. Also, tell us what you've researched and attempted so far to resolve this. Details help us help you.

Comment: I couldn't find useful articles for the above problem. But I have developed Office Addins and able to disable all Macro related buttons from the certain Tabs, by customizing the Ribbon by the following code as example `<command idMso="MacroRecord" enabled="false"/>`.